# TypeConverter on Id Column in combination with jpql

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, typeconverter

I have an database entity that is described by an barcode as its unique id.
To better use the barcode I've added a class called Barcode that contains 2 values:
- The value of the barcode
- The checksum of the barcode
Because I want to save it compactly in the database I've added an attribute converter that converts me the Barcode into an String in the format (value + checksum)

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Game implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Convert(converter = BarcodeConverter.class)
    private Barcode barcode;

    @Column
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String title;

    @Column
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String comment;
}

@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class BarcodeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Barcode, String> {

    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Barcode attribute) {
        return attribute.getValue() + attribute.getChecksum();
    }

    public Barcode convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return new Barcode(dbData);
    }
}
```

Now I'm not sure how I can use the barcode/id column in my application:

1) Is it possible to get a Game object by using:

```
entityManager.find(Game.class, new Barcode("012345", "7"));
```

2) How can I use the barcode field in a jpql query? Can I access the fields of the barcode object, or do I implicitly work on the string? 
Example if I want to select some games by their checksum do I do this by writing:

```
from Game g where g.barcode.checkum = 7
```

or

```
from Game g where g.barcode like "%7"
```

3) How are relations mapped that are realized with the use of an converter? 
Are they mapped by the string representation from the converter or by using the multiple fields of the barcode object?

Greetings 
biro

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Barcode objects in your application. Your JPA implementation (e.g. Hibernate) will use the converter for every database access to do the conversion.

You can find an example in my github repo: https://github.com/thjanssen/ColorConverter/blob/master/Converter/src/test/java/blog/thoughts/on/java/jpa21/TestColorConverter.java#L52

Comment: Can you please add an example how you would access the barcode in a jpql query?

Comment: do you need to access the string or the object then in the JPQL query?

Comment: Thank you for your example! What I want to know now is how do you make a query where you only use the blue component in your where clause. 
Do you do that with an object access in the query like:
SELECT r FROM Rectangle r WHERE color.blue = :blueValue
or do you need to work with the string in the DB to accomplish this like:
SELECT r FROM Rectangle r WHERE color like '%|%|:blue|%'